# Is this proof involving the annihilator reasonable?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, dual-spaces

I'm attempting to prove that if $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and $x \notin W$ that $\exists f \in W^0$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ where  for every subset $S$ of $V$, $S^{0} = \{f \in V^{*} : f(x) = 0 \forall x \in S \}$

My proof is as follows: Suppose $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and that $x \notin W$. $x \in V$, so $x \in V-W$.

Define a functional $f \in V^*$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \in W \\ 1 &  x \in V - W \end{cases}$$

Then $f \in W^{0}$ because for every subset $S$ of $W$, $x \in S \implies x \in W$, so $f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) \neq 0 \forall x \in V-W$

The answer I have available to me uses a more convoluted argument involving the extension of a basis for $W$. I'm wondering if this is necessary and if my proof is fine as is.

Comment: $f$ is not in $V^*$.

Comment: As JCAA pointed out, the function you defined is not linear. Using bases or something else implied by the freeness of vector spaces will indeed be necessary since this exercise is not always true for modules over a ring.

Answer (score 1):

If your space $V$ is finite-dimensional, then you can use that $\dim W^0 = \dim V -\dim W$. If $f \in W^0$ implies that $f(x)=0$ then we have
$$(W+\operatorname{span}\{x\})^0 = W^0$$
and hence
$$\dim V - \dim (W+\operatorname{span}\{x\}) = \dim V-\dim W$$
so the subspaces $W$ and $W+\operatorname{span}\{x\}$ have the same dimension so they must be equal as one contains the other. Therefore $x \in W$ which is a contradiction. We conclude that there is some $f\in W^0$ such that $f(x)\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

As is pointed in the comments, an extension of a basis for $W$ will be necessary for this, but you can also combine your idea! Suppose that $V$ is finite-dimensional, consider a basis $\beta$ for $W$ and a basis $\alpha$ for $V$ that contains $\beta$. Now define $h : \alpha \to \mathbf F$ by $h(v) = 0$ if $v \in \beta$ and $h(v) = 1$ if $v \in \alpha \setminus \beta$. Then, there is a unique linear extension $f : V \to \mathbf F$ of $h$. It follows that $f$ is your desired linear functional.